# Does the Workflow Invoke method use thread pool?

Tags: c#, performance, workflow, threadpool

I am comparing the performance of pure C# code and WF(Workflow). I use the WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(new MyWorkflow(), ...);

I want to know if Invoke() uses the thread pool.
I guess pure C# code should in any sense be faster than Workflow, right? How is the workflow actually implemented? Still by C# code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that behind the scenes it using a thread pool. The threading and execution are all managed by the Workflow Scheduler. It executes synchronously by default, but you can use BeginInvoke to run it asynchronously.

Comment: I use the thread pool in my pure C# code and find it is much faster now: seems all threads run asynchronously. Here is my code:

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(TestWorkFlow), order);

Comment: private static void TestWorkFlow(object o)
  {
   Order order = o as Order; ...}

Comment: The above is my pure C# code version. How to use this beginInvoke in my workflow version? Thanks!

Comment: I see some example. Thank you so much!

Comment: My workflow only has input parameter and don't have output. How could I use the beginInvoke? It is not working here and gives error:

Comment: Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.InvokeAsyncResult..ctor(Activity activity, IDictionary`2 inputs, WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager extensions, TimeSpan timeout, SynchronizationContext syncContext, AsyncInvokeContext invokeContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Activities.WorkflowInvoker.BeginInvoke(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)

Comment: WorkflowInvoker invoker = new WorkflowInvoker(new Workflow1());
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  IAsyncResult result = invoker.BeginInvoke(WorkflowCompletedCallback, order);

   }